# How can I use LMS5xx with sicktoolbox2?

Tags: laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make a SICK LMS511 work on ROS but I haven't been able to make it work. I am trying to use github /clearpathrobotics/laser_drivers/tree/hydro-devel with no result.

I tried moving the folder of the link above to the ROS path and then run the command rosmake in that folder. Then I tried with roslaunch launch/lms5xx.launch but I get this error:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [sicktoolbox_wrapper2/sicklms_5xx]: can't locate node [sicklms_5xx] in package [sicktoolbox_wrapper2]

I know that the laser is well connected.

What should I do?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162366/how-can-i-use-lms5xx-with-sicktoolbox2?/) by [Rodolfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/17741/rodolfo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajay Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/12121/ajay-jain/) on 2014-06-19**:
I have the exact same issue. Does anyone have information on resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use [Catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin) to compile this package.

I **highly recommend you** to do at least the [beginner tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) :)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2014-07-04**:
by highly recommend I mean "JUST DO IT" @Rodolfo @yajaniaj

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-11-04**:
Seems that the node doesn't appear even after a catkin_make :(